# Detox: Conditional test case writing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, detox

I am new to write test cases using detox for React Native app. I already wrote few test cases and working as expected.

Is it possible to add condition in test case like using if-else.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using a try catch block. An example is:

```
try {
   await expect(element(by.text(user))).toExist();
} catch (e) {
   const userField = by.id(Account.LoginView.userNameInput);
   await element(userField).tap();
   await element(userField).replaceText(user);
}
```